# How to insert PHP code into the Drupal 7 block with PHPFilter to enable a html form working?

Tags: input-formats, external-scripts

- ```
  <form action="run_pipeline.php" method="post">

  Insert SRA  identifier <input type="text" name="email"><br> <input
  type="submit" value="Run data processing pipeline"> </form>

  <?php

  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  This code I have put to a custom block to make a webform to save data input to a file.
  Where to put the run_pipeline.php which contains the code for saving data input to Excel and running Python scripts? Or should I put it right here in tags? Now it says: The requested page "/drupal/run_pipeline.php" could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing php codes inside admin blocks better to create custom blocks and specify ur php file and write custom code there.